# How to disperse data so that it can be seen clearly on a graph

Tags: data-visualization, data-transformation

I have several sets of points. Example of a set is as the following:

```
[4.392576848e-10, 0.000003411696156, 4.9441946972e-9, 8.610151880000001e-12, 483.99995160000003, 0.000063740127352, 2.92362263292e-9, 1.89848739608e-8]
```

I am trying to plot this in javascript on a [radar chart](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/polar-spider)

However, the values seem too small to distinguish this. Is it possible to use any tranformation to disperse the values so that they are easy to see.

PS: I tried simple things like multiplying them by a constant.

Comment: The question here is about transformations for display of data, not about use of javascript, so seems to me to be on-topic here

Comment: Why did multiplying them not do what you want?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]Take the natural logarithm of the values and plot those. Or, plot the native values  on a logarithmic scale. If you find it easier to understand and explain, the take the logarithm base 10.